# Verify map with custom values

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have the following map:

```
Map<String, MyCustomObject>
```

My goal is to verify capacity of this map using **hamcrest matchers**. I've tried the following approach:

```
assertThat(map, hasEntry("key", (MyCustomObject)hasItem(hasProperty("propertyName", equalTo("value")))));
```

But looks like that `hasItem` method works only with collections.

Is there any alternative method for verifying custom objects?

`new MyCustomObject()` does not work in my case because test fails by hashcode equality. And, another thing is that I cannot modify `MyCustomObject class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you use this?

```
assertThat(map.get("key"), hasProperty("propertyName", equalTo("value")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that there is at least one key--any key--that matches the value, use `hasValue`:

```
assertThat(map, hasValue(hasProperty("propertyName", is("value"))));
```

The difference is in the mismatch output. There are also matchers for `hasKey` and `hasEntry`.